# Solution deployed to a web application errors when not using FQDN

Tags: lookup-column

EDIT: using SP2010, with Enterprise and Publishing features enabled at the WebApp and site where intend to use the feature.

We have a 3rd party solution (Lookup with Picker [ilovesharpoint.fields.lookupfieldwitrhpciker.wsp]) deployed to a single web application in our farm, and it works as intended when I am visiting the fully qualifed URL.

Unfortunately, it errors when using a short URL.

The alternate access mapping is set for both FQDN and short in CA, like this:
htp://mycompany.sharepoint.com (default zone) 
&
htp://mycompany (intranet zone).

Unfortunately, my UAT environments dont have alternate mapping, and I want to avoid unnecessary changes if/where posssible.

Sp logs show:

```
07/28/2017 13:06:10.55  w3wp.exe (0x1C98)                           0x162EC SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:/test/_layouts/FldNewEx.aspx?List=%7BFC9C90ED%2DB4C2%2D469F%2D888D%2D54532C2BB11E%7D&FieldTypeParam=LookupFieldWithPicker&DisplayNameParam=&DescriptionParam=&VldFormulaParam=&VldMessageParam=)  eaf44ba8-8ead-4175-b79c-4d6603914701
07/28/2017 13:06:10.55  w3wp.exe (0x1C98)                           0x162EC SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  eaf44ba8-8ead-4175-b79c-4d6603914701
07/28/2017 13:06:10.58  w3wp.exe (0x1C98)                           0x162EC Document Management Server      Document Management             52od    Medium      MetadataNavigationContext Page_InitComplete: No XsltListViewWebPart was found on this page[/_layouts/FldNewEx.aspx?List=%7BFC9C90ED%2DB4C2%2D469F%2D888D%2D54532C2BB11E%7D&FieldTypeParam=LookupFieldWithPicker&DisplayNameParam=&DescriptionParam=&VldFormulaParam=&VldMessageParam=].  Hiding key filters and downgrading tree functionality to legacy ListViewWebPart(v3) level for this list.   eaf44ba8-8ead-4175-b79c-4d6603914701
07/28/2017 13:06:10.58  w3wp.exe (0x1C98)                           0x162EC SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resources.iLoveSharePoint.Fields.LookupFieldWithPicker.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources.4geskbgx" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.    at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)     at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)     at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)     at System.Re... eaf44ba8-8ead-4175-b79c-4d6603914701
07/28/2017 13:06:10.58* w3wp.exe (0x1C98)                           0x162EC SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...sources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)     at System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.GetObject(String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)     at System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture, Type objType, String propName)     at System.Web.HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(String classKey, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Search.SPSatelliteResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResource(String classKey, String resourceKey)     at ASP._controltemplates_ilovesharepoint_lookupfieldwithpicker_lookupfieldwithpickereditor_ascx.__BuildControlinputFormControlWeb()     at ASP._controltemplates_ilovesharepoin...  eaf44ba8-8ead-4175-b79c-4d6603914701
07/28/2017 13:06:10.58* w3wp.exe (0x1C98)                           0x162EC SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...t_lookupfieldwithpicker_lookupfieldwithpickereditor_ascx.__BuildControlpanelEditor()     at ASP._controltemplates_ilovesharepoint_lookupfieldwithpicker_lookupfieldwithpickereditor_ascx.__BuildControlTree(_controltemplates_ilovesharepoint_lookupfieldwithpicker_lookupfieldwithpickereditor_ascx __ctrl)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(IWebObjectFactory objectFactory, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type t, Object[] parameters)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldCustomizationPage.CreateChildControls()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldNewPage.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldCustomizationPage....  eaf44ba8-8ead-4175-b79c-4d6603914701
07/28/2017 13:06:10.58* w3wp.exe (0x1C98)                           0x162EC SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldNewPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) eaf44ba8-8ead-4175-b79c-4d6603914701
07/28/2017 13:06:10.60  w3wp.exe (0x1C98)                           0x162EC SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:/test/_layouts/FldNewEx.aspx?List=%7BFC9C90ED%2DB4C2%2D469F%2D888D%2D54532C2BB11E%7D&FieldTypeParam=LookupFieldWithPicker&DisplayNameParam=&DescriptionParam=&VldFormulaParam=&VldMessageParam=)). Execution Time=46.7704 eaf44ba8-8ead-4175-b79c-4d6603914701
```

Comment: which SharePoint version are you working on?

Comment: SP2010 with Enterprise and Publishing features enabled in the webapp